# Proof of local isometry, Riemannian manifolds. Is my proof correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

There is one exercise I proved involving that a smooth map $\varphi$ from $M$ to $\widetilde{M}$ is a local isometry if and only if (pullback) $(\varphi^* \tilde{g})=g.$

So I am wondering if the proof is correct? Below is both the exercise and my proof:

Exercise:

- Prove that if $(M,g)$ and $(\widetilde{M}, \tilde{g})$ are Riemannian manifolds with $\dim M = \dim \widetilde{M}$, then a smooth map $\varphi : M \to \widetilde{M}$ is a local isometry if and only if $\varphi^* \tilde{g} = g$.

My proof:
Recall that an isometry from $(M,g)$ to $(\widetilde{M}, \tilde{g})$ is given by a diffeomorphism $\varphi : M \to \widetilde{M}$ with the pullback $\varphi^* \tilde{g} = g$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
    \forall v, w \in T_pM, \forall p \in M : \,  g_p(v,w) = \tilde{g}_{\varphi(p)}(d\varphi_p(v), d\varphi_p(w)).
\end{equation*}
Now, let $(M,g)$ and $(\widetilde{M}, \tilde{g})$ be Riemannian manifolds with the same dimension, and define a smooth map as
$$
C^\infty(M)\ni \varphi : M \to \widetilde{M}.
$$
($\implies$) Assume $\varphi$ is a local isometry. The pullback $\varphi^* \tilde{g} = g$ is then
$$
\left(\varphi^* \tilde{g}\right)_p(v,w) = \tilde{g}_{\varphi(p)}(d\varphi_p(v), d\varphi_p(w)),
$$
since there exists an isometry between $T_pM$ and $T_{\varphi(p)} \widetilde{M}$, then we get
$$
\left(\varphi^* \tilde{g}\right)_p(v,w) = \tilde{g}_{\varphi(p)}(d\varphi_p(v), d\varphi_p(w)) = g_p(v,w).
$$
Hence it follows that $\varphi^*\tilde{g} = g$.

($\impliedby$) Suppose $\varphi^*\tilde{g} = g$. Then for all $p \in M$ and arbitrary chosen tangent vectors $v,w \in T_pM$ we have from before
$$
 \left(\varphi^* \tilde{g}\right)_p(v,w) = \tilde{g}_{\varphi(p)}(d\varphi_p(v), d\varphi_p(w)) = g_p(v,w).
$$
Since the differential $d\varphi_p : T_pM \to T_{\varphi(p)}\widetilde{M}$ preserves the inner product and it is a linear isometry, therefore $\varphi$ is a local isometry and  $\varphi^*\tilde{g} = g$.

Comment: In your very first sentence, what does it even mean to say a map $M\to\tilde M$ is a linear isometry?

Comment: I see now a mistake in my proof. I am reading the lecture notes https://www.math.ru.nl/~burtscher/lecturenotes/2223RGnotes.pdf and I´ve switched between two definitions:

Comment: The first part is essentially a tautology, because this precisely how a local isometry is defined. The second part doesn't actually prove that $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism

Comment: Definition 2.12: \textbf{Definition 2.12.} A map \(\varphi: M \rightarrow M'\) is a \textit{local isometry} between Riemannian manifolds
\((M, g)\) and \((\tilde{M}, \tilde{g}\) if for each point \(p \in M\) there exists a neighborhood \(U\) such that \(\varphi|_U\) is an
isometry onto an open subset in \(\tilde{M}\).

Comment: My point is that "linear isometry" makes sense only for a *linear* mapping between vector spaces (with inner products or norms). It makes no sense for a mapping between manifolds.

Comment: I suspect that you miswrote your title and your opening sentence. When you wrote "linear isometry", was it perhaps your intention to instead write "local isometry"?

Comment: An apology! I misspelled. I meant local isometry. But I believe that the second part of the proof I should rather prove that $\varphi$ is a local diffeomorphism between the manifolds and hence it is proven? Like @Chris suggested

Comment: @ShireHobbit145 correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement is a tautology, given a local isometry $\phi$, we must have that $\phi^*\tilde{g}=g$. Now let $\phi$ be a smooth map, we need to show that given $\phi^*\tilde{g}=g$, $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism.

By the inverse function theorem, it suffices to check that $D_p\phi$ is an isomorphism for all $p\in M$, and since dimensions are equal it suffices to check that $D_p\phi$ is injective. We proceed by contradiction, suppose that $D_p\phi$ is not injective, and let $v\in \ker D_p\phi$. Then for all $w\in T_pM$:
$$g_p(v,w)=(\phi^*\tilde{g})_p(v,w)=g_{\phi(p)}(D_p\phi v,D_p\phi w)=0$$
It follows that $g_p$ is degenerate, a contradiction. So $D_p\phi$ is injective at all $p\in M$, and $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism.